# Mosquitto on Apache reverse proxy with SSL (and docker)

Tags: docker, apache, mqtt, reverse-proxy, mosquitto

What I want to do is to run eclipse-mosquitto as an MQTT broker behind an Apache reverse proxy with SSL.

I have written the following docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:2
    container_name: mosquitto
    ports:
      - "9100:9100"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mosquitto_data:/mosquitto/data
      - mosquitto_log:/mosquitto/log
      - ./mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf

volumes:
  mosquitto_data: {}
  mosquitto_log: {}
```

And the following `mosquitto.conf`:

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/

log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
log_dest stdout

port 1883
listener 9108
protocol websockets
```

Now, I want to add the Apache reverse proxy to add SSL to my broker. I usually use subdomains to keep the services I'm running on my server separate.

This is what I have written:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mosquitto.example.com

    # SSL settings (mostly generated by Webmin)
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/example/ssl.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/example/ssl.key
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/example/ssl.ca

    # Proxy stuff
    ProxyPass /  ws://localhost:9100/
    ProxyPassReverse /  ws://localhost:9100/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, on a client, `mosquitto_pub` gives me this:

```
.\mosquitto_pub -h mosquitto.example.com -p 443 -u admin -p admin1234 -t 'test/topic' -m 'helloWorld'
Unable to connect (This feature is not supported.).
```

The credentials were created with `mosquitto_passwd`.

What am I doing wrong?

Bonus question:
How can I make it so I don't need the `-p 443`?

Answer (score 3):

The `mosquitto_pub` and `mosquitto_sub` commands do not support connecting to a broker with MQTT over Websockets.

You can use the nodejs based tools that come with the mqtt package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#cli